# Is there a way to expose the WinRT api to lua/love2d?

Tags: winapi, uwp, lua, windows-runtime, love2d

I'm trying to get access to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.speechsynthesis.speechsynthesizer?view=winrt-19041 so that I can use TTS, specifically TTS with SSML in a game that I am working on. However, I feel like I've been getting the run around when trying to find information on whether it's possible, and the easiest way a total smooth brain like me could do it.

Things I've tried so far:

1. Tried building and using LuaCOM. Think I was barking up the wrong tree here, not sure that you can access the API that way.
2. Building and using LuaInterface. It's like 8 years old, I'm not sure I was even using it correctly. I think it's more like a wrapper or something for spinning up it's own lua instance. Also, building it was an absolute nightmare.
3. Using Unmanaged Exports to write and build a dll that I could load in lua. Maybe? I don't know, I was never able to get DllExport or UE to ever work.

Comment: It doesn't appear that Lua can easily interface with C in a way required by the Windows Runtime. It's probably easiest to put the Windows Runtime code into a native DLL that exports its functionality in a way that can be consumed by Lua.

Comment: Can you point me in a direction? Hopefully something someone with very little C based experience could understand?

Comment: To speak something, you may simply create temporary file "file.vbs" with content `CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak("Words to say")` and run it from Lua as `os.execute("wscript file.vbs")`